# React xarrows going beyond the modal. Tried zindex but no use

Tags: html, css, svg, modal-dialog, z-index

[image]
[image]

I'm using react Xarrows library to draw lines/arrows between some tree nodes. I checked solutions that suggest z-index. But unfortunately that didn't help. I tried setting the z-index of the Xarrow to -100 hoping it would solve the issue. But that is hiding the arrow within the modal instead of hiding beyond the modal. I inspected the Xarrow and copied the HTML here

```
<div end="OHU_b538739e925033c2839f51dea6faf155#mapperButton" style="position: absolute;">
  <svg width="382.17047119140625" height="391.47439765930176" overflow="auto" style="position: absolute; left: 163.756px; top: -473.275px; pointer-events: none;">
<path d="M 16 16 L  36 16 L 36 375.47439765930176 L  366.17047119140625 375.47439765930176" stroke="#9DC5ED" stroke-dasharray="0 0" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visibleStroke"></path>
```

Comment: Are you trying to assign z-index to a `<path>` element?

Comment: No to svg element

Comment: Hey, I'm the author of react-xarrows, does this issue persist?(z index is now available as property directly)